# htaccess 'Pretty URLs' not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't get my URLs rewritten to SEO-friendly ones. I've tried a lot of snippets from here and other places but none of them appear to work - I'm not sure why!

The rewrite engine is definately working and enabled as I am using it for domain and IP canocialisation. Just fails to work with URL rewriting.

I want the URLs to read; **xxx.com/profile/Name** instead of **xxx.com/profile.php?user=Name**.

**The code I'm currently trying is;**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

**My full htaccess code is;**

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/CE/?404=1&page=1

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# Set XSS Protection header
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>

# allow all except those indicated here
<Files *>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 188.143.232.32
deny from 188.143.232.27
deny from 188.143.234.155
deny from 188.143.*.*
</Files>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ /profile.php?user=$1 [L]

# Canocial IP
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^217\.160\.0\.148 [nc,or]

# Canocial URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.xxx\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/xxx\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive on

    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 3 days"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 3 days"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

I've had problems with this stuff before on another project and never really resolved them so it'd be good to find a solution that works.

Note: I have checked many other 'solutions' on Stack Overflow - none that I have tried have worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like below rule,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

Above I removed a leading slash from profile.php which might be a problem.

Comment: Works - thank you! But is now causing an issue with a gallery which takes the user variable and uses it in a SQL query to retrieve images. I have some code that displays a place holder if no image is available or cannot be retrieved. They are just broken images now that flash.

Comment: Are you getting the user variable inside profile.php if getting then it is another issue please try `<base href="yourdomain/">` inside your page.

Comment: I've just tested in production and it is working as far as rewriting the URL goes but all of the information from the database isn't showing - it is just showing a blank, unpopulated template. I already have the base href configured. The variable is being used in the profile.php file.

Comment: If you are not using rewrite is it working correctly i mean using `profile.php?user=value`?

Comment: Yes it is. It's populating the loops in the template as it should. In dev (localhost) the rewrite works fine - just the issue with broken images but that's an error in other code I can fix later - but it is pulling things like bio and images (if they exist) through. In production the rewrite works (that is it takes you to the correct page) but just not for the data (meaning it's not populating the page).